# not able to login to the desired location

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\Website\storeadmin\admin_login.php..and the same for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224291/undefined-index-username-in-c-wamp-www-website-storeadmin-admin-login-php-and)

```
//admin_login.php
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["member"])){
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}

?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){     // <-  Check the user has clicked the button
  $manager = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_POST["username"]);
  $password = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_POST["password"]);



include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username ='$manager' AND password ='$password'LIMIT 1");
$exist_count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($exist_count == 1){
    while(mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        }

    $_SESSION["id"]= $id;
    $_SESSION["manager"]= $manager;
    $_SESSION["password"]= $password;
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();

    }
    else{
    echo 'This information is incorrect,try again <a href = "index.php">Click Here</a>';
    exit();
    }
}




?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> AdminLogin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
<div  id="mainWrapper" > 
    <?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
    <div id="pageContent" > 
    <div align="left" "style="margin-left:040px;"><h1>Please login to continue</h1><br />
    </div>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="admin_login.php"> 
    UserName<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="40"/>
    Password<br />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="40"/> 
    <br />
    <br />
    <br /> 
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="LogIn"/>  
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
//index.php
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["member"])){
    header("location:admin_login.php");
    exit();
}

$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i',"",$_SESSION["id"]);
$manager = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_SESSION["manager"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_SESSION["password"]);


include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id ='managerID' AND username ='$manager' AND password ='$password'LIMIT 1");
$exist_count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($exist_count == 0){
    echo("Your login session data in not in the database");
    exit();
}



?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Service Admin Area</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
<div  id="mainWrapper" > 
    <?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
    <div id="pageContent" > 
    <div align="left" "style="margin-left:040px;"><h1>Hello Store Manager .What would you loke to do today</h1><br />
    <h3><a href="inventory_list.php">Manage Inventory</a></h3><br/><h3><a href="">Manage Me</a></h3><br/></div></div>
    <?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to login to my `index.php` page even after I have put in the correct username and password as specified in my database which I have set through phpmyadmin. Everytime I try to login it invokes the `echo 'This information is incorrect,try again Click Here'` as mentioned in the `admin_login.php`. I am getting a bit frustrated. Can you help me out guys?

Comment: Please try to post only relevant code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: is your sql even running? is a space not required between $password and limit? SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username ='$manager' AND password ='$password' LIMIT 1

Comment: @NicholasKing the sql is running.The problem still persists after that space thing you mentioned.

Comment: @user1485323 and are the values you expect inside username and password?

Comment: also what does the var $exist_count contain?

Comment: also why have you got preg_replace it looks like it is emptying you variables

Answer (score 1):

Try some debugging;

- Check the values of $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] before and after your preg_replace calls.
- Add an 'or die mysql_error()' to your call to mysql_query() to see if that is running ok
- Echo out the value of $sql so you can have a look at the query.
- Does the header() command not require a space between the name and value? or a \r\n afterwards? Worth double-checking.
- Generally provide more output at various stages and it should be trivial to track down the issue.

And (once it is working), please please add a crypt() or md5() + salt to your password field in the database.

Answer (score 0):

im pretty sure the preg_replace is emptying your variables

```
$manager = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_POST["username"]);   $password = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z0-9]#i',"",$_POST["password"]);
```

according to the php docs http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

have you tried removing them?